# Docking Ranges and Conditions

Tags: roomle

I have a part that is a rectangle of 1200mm x 400mm x 400mm, this part can be divided into 3 equal sizes, within these equal sizes I need to Dock different parts. I have set a Docking Range for every 400mm (which is fine) I have 3 style of parts that need to Dock into the 400mm gaps, so I have set on the main 1200 part 3 KEYS (bridgePos1InfillType, bridgePos2InfillType, bridgePos3InfillType) and currently when I dock a part inside these I set the TYPE that was docked...

```
        "mask": "cubby",
            "position": "{0, 0, 40}",
            "stepEnd": "{800, 0, 0}",
            "rotation": "{0, 0, 0}",
            "condition": "(((configID=='v2')||(configLadderID=='v2'))&&(cubeHeight==400))",
            "maxConnections": 1,
            "stepX": 400,
            "stepY": 0,
            "stepZ": 0,
            "assignmentScripts": {
                "onDock": "index = connection.index; 
                if(index=='0'){bridgePos1InfillType='cubby'};
                if(index=='1'){bridgePos2InfillType='cubby'};
                if(index=='2'){bridgePos3InfillType='cubby'}",
                "onUpdate" : "",
                "onUnDock": "index = connection.index; 
                if(index=='0'){bridgePos1InfillType='blank'};
                if(index=='1'){bridgePos2InfillType='blank'};
                if(index=='2'){bridgePos3InfillType='blank'}"
            }
```

But what I want to happen is when I then try to docking a different part (using Docking Range) it should not let me as the InFillType is not BLANK

this is my next part to dock but how do I check to see if the Docking Range Position in already taken or that the bridgePos1InFillType is not BLANK...

```
     {
            "mask": "cupboard400x400",
            "position": "{0, 0, 40}",
            "stepEnd": "{800, 0, 0}",
            "rotation": "{0, 0, 0}",
            "condition": "index = connection.index; 
            (((configID=='v2')||(configLadderID=='v2'))&&(cubeHeight==400))",
            "maxConnections": 1,
            "stepX": 400,
            "stepY": 0,
            "stepZ": 0
        },
```

Answer (score 2):

You can utilize internal value called `condition` in all condition statements, like this:

```
"condition": "
    /* you probably want to check if you're in preview, otherwise you could delete it right after docking, if the condition result becomes false */
    if (connection.isPreview) {
        /* then checking against which internal var to check this */
        if (connection.index == 1) { condition = bridgePos1InfillType == 'blank'; }
        ...
        /* then you can do further checks like */
        condition = condition && (!maximumLoadExceeded);
    } else {
        /* if it is already there, just don't worry & keep it */
        condition = true;
    }
"
```

There is `connection.index` or `connection.position` to check the current position in the range's array. For 2D ranges, I recommend approach of computing the indices from `connection.position`. For 1D range, `connection.index` works just fine. See https://docs.roomle.com/scripting/resources/200_80_dockingbasics.html#docking-ranges and https://docs.roomle.com/scripting/resources/200_140_advanceddockinglogic.html#docking-ranges

I also see that an array would be good for you. If you worry only about whether there is something already docked, you could do an array of booleans `occupied = [0,0,0]` and then access the values using `get(self.occupied, connection.index)` in condition and use the `set` function in assignment scripts. If you need to also know what is occupied, RoomleScript unfortunately only supports arrays of numbers. A possible solution would be to have a 1:1 constant numeric identifier for every type.

See also https://docs.roomle.com/scripting/resources/200_40_roomlescript.html#arrays